# mySQL shutdown "ERROR: 1050 Table 'plugin' already exists"

Tags: mysql, innodb

Have a mySQL DB (running on a Debian LAMP) that seems to do a maintenance shutdown or check each night, and fails with the following. The only "plugin" table is the empty one in the mysql db, and I'm not sure why that would upset InnoDB, as the mysql table is of course MyISAM.

I could brute force it by exporting and importing the DB but I'd rather 'solve' it if I can - plus, I'm not sure if that's even going to fix it. Have 5 slaves running off it that I'd then have to reset, if nothing else!

If I just start mySQL when this happens, it's happy until the next night. Rinse, repeat. Ugh. Done a tonne of googling, maybe my fu is lacking.

Thoughts?

```
180524 22:35:05 InnoDB: 5.5.60 started; log sequence number 44207917672
ERROR: 1050  Table 'plugin' already exists
180524 22:35:05 [ERROR] Aborting

180524 22:35:05  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
180524 22:35:06  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 44207917672
180524 22:35:06 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Ok, after much digging, it's the nightly cron-apt job. Shuts down mysql, fails to do an updatety thing, then mysql falls over on restart. I'll just kill the cron-apt job for now, until I get a chance to figure out why.

Comment: any update you get for this issue? I encountered the same for my zabbix appliance...

Comment: Sorry, bit late to notice your message gray13. I never did. Once our current project is done (only a couple of months) I'll recreate and reimport. Didn't want the hassle (or risk!) mid-project.